# How to declare a nested resource in activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-routing

I have a resource called User and another one called Order.

I want Order to be nested inside Users so I can have these routes:

```
/users
/users/:id
/users/:id/new
/users/:id/edit
/users/:user_id/orders
/users/:user_id/orders/:id
/users/:user_id/orders/:id/new
/users/:user_id/orders/:id/edit
```

How can I do that with activeadmin?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just add belongs_to option to active_admin resource page

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: It works. Although it also add default routes: /orders, /orders/:id, etc.

Answer (score 13):

@railscard's answer is partially correct, but if you don't want the default routes like /order, /order/:id etc like mentioned by @bishma-stornelli - you could add the option like this :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  belongs_to :user, :optional => true
end
```

Comment: Looks like they've changed the defaults, because now when I've added `optional: true`, i got access to both `/users/:user_id/orders` and `/orders` (which I was looking for)

Comment: If you still want your belongs_to resources to be available in the default menu and through non-nested routes, you can use the :optional option. [active_admin docs](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#belongs-to)